update-alternatives: error: unknown argument
I'm trying to employ update-alternatives for different versions of OpenSSL on an Ubuntu 22 machine.  The following works for OpenSSL 3 (after sudo -i):
update-alternatives \
--install /usr/bin/openssl openssl /usr/local/openssl/3.3.2/bin/openssl 3030200 \
--slave /usr/local/bin/openssl openssl_ /usr/local/openssl/3.3.2/bin/openssl \
--slave /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so libssl /usr/local/openssl/3.3.2/lib64/libssl.so.3 \
--slave /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 libssl_ /usr/local/openssl/3.3.2/lib64/libssl.so.3 \
--slave /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so libcrypto /usr/local/openssl/3.3.2/lib64/libcrypto.so.3 \
--slave /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 libcrypto_ /usr/local/openssl/3.3.2/lib64/libcrypto.so.3 \
--slave /usr/include/openssl openssl_include /usr/local/openssl/3.3.2/include/openssl

However, for OpenSSL 1, I get update-alternatives: error: unknown argument '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1':
update-alternatives \
--install /usr/bin/openssl openssl /usr/local/openssl/1.1.1w/bin/openssl 1010123 \
--slave /usr/local/bin/openssl openssl_ /usr/local/openssl/1.1.1w/bin/openssl \
--slave /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so libssl /usr/local/openssl/1.1.1w/lib/libssl.so.1.1 \
--slave /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 libssl_ /usr/local/openssl/1.1.1w/lib/libssl.so.1.1 \
--slave /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so libcrypto /usr/local/openssl/1.1.1w/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 \
--slave /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 libcrypto_ /usr/local/openssl/1.1.1w/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 \
--slave /usr/include/openssl openssl_include /usr/local/openssl/1.1.1w/include/openssl

I have tried establishing alternatives for OpenSSL 1 before OpenSSL 3, but I get the same error result.  I have confirmed that all the target files for OpenSSL 1 exist on my file system.
Can anyone explain this?  Is there a known problem with update-altervatives that accounts for my experience here?
